# Finding an overgroup or a subgroup in PGL

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrices

Let k be a nonperfect field of characteristic $2$. Let $a\in k\backslash k^2$, $G=PGL_4(k)$ and and $$H= \left\{ \small\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
                                                      x & ay &az & aw\\
                                                      w & x  &ay & az \\
                                                      z & w  & x & ay \\
                                                      y & z  & w & x  \\
                                                    \end{array}  
                                             \right] \in PGL_4(k) \mid x, y, z, w \in k \right\}.$$ Can anybody find a connected proper overgroup or a nontrivial connected proper subgroup of $H$ in $G$?

Comment: Note that $H$ is a group.

Comment: Do $w$ and $z$ vary across $k$ too?

Comment: Being pedantic: I guess the trivial subgroup answers the second part of your question.

Comment: Thanks for comments. The trivial subgroup is not what I want. I am looking for positive dimensional subgroups. Also, I would like to know what happens if k is algebraically closed field of characteristic 2? Are there any over/sub groups of $H$ in $PGL_4(\bar k)$?

Comment: OK, for a connected subgroup of dimension 1 just take $y=w=0$. The resulting set is is an abelian unipotent subgroup (in particular it has exponent $2$). In fact, if I am not mistaken, over $\overline{k}$ it looks like a root group for $PSp_4(k)$. (Although the question over $\overline{k}$ needs clarification because in this context one cannot choose $a$ to be a non-square.)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning in the question that $H$ is abelian in general.

Comment: For an overgroup take the normalizer of the connected subgroup of dimension $1$ that I describe above.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comment. I have another question. Now let $H'$ be the one dimensional unipotent subgroup of $H$ obtained by taking $y=w=0$. Are there infinitely many overgroups of $H'$ in $PGL_4(k)$? Please forget my last comment on finding overgroups of $H$ in $PGL_4(\bar {k})$.

Comment: Tomo, I think $H'$ **does** have an infinite number of overgroups - you just need to caclulate its normalizer to see this... But I haven't time to do the details... If you restrict to **connected** overgroups then the answer might be different...